# at the time/al momento (Latinoamérica)

Tags: gramática

Quisiera saber si en el español de latinoamérica es correcto traducir "at the time" como "al momento".

- Where were you **at the time** that things started happening in relation to the Wal-Mart's parking lot?
- Donde te encontrabas cuando partieron las cosas en el estacionamiento de Wal-Mart?
- Donde te encontrabas cuando sucedieron los hechos del estacionamiento de Wal-Mart?
- Donde te encontrabas cuando sucedió lo de el estacionamiento de Wal-Mart?
- Donde estuviste **al momento** de lo ocurrido en el estacionamiento de Wal-Mart?

También si se tiene que usar necesariamente el genitivo sajón Wal-Mart's parking lot. Gracias =)

Comment: Does your English sentence actually read: in relation to the Wal-Mart's parking lot??

Comment: Yes, it does; in relation to the Wal-Mart's parking lot? 
I'm not sure I get that question.

Comment: @Lambie The question makes more sense to me as “Where were you in relation to the Wal-Mart's parking lot at the time that things started happening?” It sounds like something a witness to an incident would be asked, to which the answer might be “I was across the road”, or “in the adjacent lot”

Comment: @Traveller You may be right. Also, in relation to means: with regard to. Whereas here, they seem to want to say "in the Walmart parking lot". Not, with regard to the subject of the parking lot. Also, "at the time of" is merely when. Even in English. I just wonder if the sentence comes from some "official source" like a lawyer or DA, or if it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traduciría "at the time" como:

- al momento

si es seguido por una frase preposicional con "de":

- ¿Dónde estabas **al momento de** los incidentes en el estacionamiento de Wal-Mart?

En cambio, lo traduciría como:

- en el momento

si es seguido por una proposición relativa con "en que":

- ¿Dónde estabas **en el momento en que** se iniciaron / produjeron los incidentes en el estacionamiento de Wal-Mart?

Comment: 'en el momento en que se' es lógica y suena bien.

Comment: En el momento makes more sense.

Comment: @FairOPShotgun "al momento de" is also very usual with prepositional phrases, ej. al momento de su muerte (at the time of his death)